# Visual C++ with multiple Application Forms

Tags: .net, forms, winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli

I am currently developing a program called SCCG in C++ using .Net framework. I have a form called `MainForm` that does basically everything, and another form called `LoadingForm` that does some SQL Server queries.

In order to start the program I am using this code:

```
#include "MainForm.hpp"

[STAThread]
void main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    SCCG::MainForm^ form = gcnew SCCG::MainForm();
    Application::Run(form);
}
```

My problem is that I need to show the LoadingForm and execute its queries (what can take several seconds) before showing the MainForm, thus working as a load screen for the program. This way the user does not think that the program stopped working.

Do you know how can I do this?

Comment: You probably should separate the code making the queries from any form instance.

Comment: My option right now is to create a separate program to perform the queries, because if the server is offline the MainForm CAN NOT start, so whatever form performs the queries, it must perform before the MainForm.

Comment: I think what you want is a splash screen: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/060d4e8b-48e1-4e26-9ee3-7142e48631a7/how-to-create-a-splash-screen-in-visual-c-for-window-form?forum=Vsexpressvc

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz Huh what? What have splash screens have to do with this question?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ he wants to show a "loading progress" dialog before the main form is shown. That is usually handled in a "splash screen" type of way.

Comment: Another option is to show the LoadingForm, and then when the loading is finished, show the MainForm and close the LoadingForm. Just be sure that closing the LoadingForm doesn't cause the program to exit.

Comment: @marceloatg You missed my point, perform the queries at startup without instantiating any forms yet. Decide on results if to startup the GUI, and feed the forms with valid results if you have such.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I think you missed the point, he wants to inform the user that something is happening before starting the queries and while they're running. Then when completed, show the MainForm. This requires showing some GUI then the mainform. Hence, the splash screen idea.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes I missed, but still what I'm trying to avoid is to have the user waiting for a few minutes before the MainForm is shown, that is why it would be nice do show a form, the LoadingForm.

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz The splash screen seems to be what I am looking for, but I checked the link you have sent and I can't make it to work, and the guy who posted the question on the link couldn't make it to work as well. But thank you, that was a close shot!

Comment: @marceloatg Perhaps in the `OnLoad` of the MainForm you can show another, loading, form, do your queries, and then close the loading form when done.

Comment: another option is to disable the mainform, do the queries in a background thread, and when the background thread is done, re-enable the mainform.

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz I tried that, but somehow the LoadingForm does not load the background image, it shows the form, with blank background, perform the queries and then closes. Meanwhile the MainForm is shown behind the LoadingForm, so the user can see both forms.

Comment: You need to call `Application.DoEvents()` periodically.

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz ok, I will study how to do that, thank you so far!